# How to access fields with StrategyPattern in Python?

Tags: python, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to use the Strategy Pattern to include different behaviours for different sizes of a simulation.

I came across [this implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20718/strategy-design-pattern-with-various-duck-type-classes) from the first example of the book  [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124).

However, I don't understand where and how should I access my data initialised in my simulation.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
###########################################################################    #####
# Abstract Simulation class and concrete Simulation type classes.
################################################################################

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, run, plot):
        self._run_behavior = run
        self._plot_behavior = plot

    def run(self):
        return self._run_behavior.run()

    def plot(self):
        return self._plot_behavior.plot()        

class SmallSimulation(Simulation):
    def __init__(self):
        Simulation.__init__(self, Run(), Plot())
        print "I'm a small simulation"
        self.data = 'Small Data'

class BigSimulation(Simulation):
    def __init__(self):
        Simulation.__init__(self, Run(), Plot())
        print "I'm a big simulation"
        self.data = 'Big Data'

class LargeSimulation(Simulation):
    def __init__(self):
        Simulation.__init__(self, RunLarge(), Plot())
        print "I'm a large simulation"
        self.data = 'Large Data'

################################################################################
# Run behavior interface and behavior implementation classes.
################################################################################

class RunBehavior:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod 
    def run(self):
        pass

class Run(RunBehavior):
    def run(self):
        print "I'm running standard"
        print self.data

class RunLarge(RunBehavior):
    def run(self):
        print "I'm running multilevel"


################################################################################
# Plot behavior interface and behavior implementation classes.
################################################################################

class PlotBehavior:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod 
    def plot(self):
        pass

class Plot(PlotBehavior):
    def plot(self):
        print "I'm plotting results"

################################################################################
# Test Code.
################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    smallSimulation = SmallSimulation()
    bigSimulation = BigSimulation()
    largeSimulation = LargeSimulation()

    print('='*20)
    print('Execution')
    smallSimulation.run()
    bigSimulation.run()
    largeSimulation.run()

    print('='*20)
    print('Plotting')
    smallSimulation.plot()
    bigSimulation.plot()
    largeSimulation.plot()
```

The output is

```
I'm a small simulation
I'm a big simulation
I'm a large simulation
====================
Execution
I'm running standard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strategy.py", line 84, in <module>
    smallSimulation.run()
  File "strategy.py", line 16, in run
    return self._run_behavior.run()
  File "strategy.py", line 52, in run
    print self.data
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How should I initialise and access my data?

Comment: where is `data` supposed to come from?

Comment: If the data is independent of the simulation type, maybe pass it to the strategy to modify. If it's strategy type dependent, have an interface for representing it to other parts of your system. If it should provide basic behaviour define an interface for that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Data is supposed to be generated during the initialisation of the concrete simulation type classes (SmallSimulation, BigSimulation, and LargeSimulation)

Comment: @PeterWood Data depends on the simulation type and "run" has to modify it accordingly. I understood that StrategyPattern defines interfaces based on behaviour and not on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your run class doesn't have a data attribute, hence the exception.

```
class Run(RunBehavior):
# This class does NOT have a data attribute
    def run(self):
        print "I'm running standard"
        print self.data
```

To access simulation's `data` within `Run`, you can pass it in Run's init():

```
class Run(RunBehavior):
    def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
    def run(self):
       print "I'm running standard"
       print self.data
```

Comment: is this solution correct in terms of Data Encapsulation?

Comment: Could the person who down-voted elaborate as to why?

Comment: I don't think this violates Data Encapsulation. I mean, you have to get the data one way or another ...

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem for now. As it was pointed by @PeterWood and this article http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html I'm using an interface to pass my data to Run.